# Reliable MIDI playback using a soundbank on Java

Tags: java, macos, midi, javasound, javax.sound.midi

I'm writing an application that plays some midi notes, and I'm having trouble with soundbanks.

On the default JVM for Mac, there is a `soundbank-mid.gm` present, but Java tells me there is no default soundbank and no instruments loaded. It also fails to load my own SoundFont file. It still plays from some default though.

On my JVM 7, there is a default soundbank and loaded instruments, it also loads SF2 files. I have a native dep that doesn't work on 7 though.

On Ubuntu I had similar problems, but that was because `soundbank.gm` is not installed by default. I was also able to load `SF2` files just fine.

Never tried Windows.

What is a reliable way to play midi across platforms?

Comment: Unfortunately, Sun never seemed to get a workable x-plat MIDI API together.  It works OK on Windows (most of the time), but support on *nix has always been patchy, and OS X - abysmal.

Comment: http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html
This was where I went for a lot of information which ~ 3 years ago was really helpful. I'm sure there's a custom player out there somewhere.

Comment: Did you try to add the Gervill jar manually to your project? In my case (Orarcle JVM 7 on Ubuntu x64) the new JVM shipped with Gervill as default synth (=> SF2 supported by default) but I don't know if this is also the case for Mac. Including Gervill manually should provide a identical synth for all platforms